# dataTables flattens JSON data on POSTing, how to decode into python dictionary

Tags: python, flask, datatables

I am using the jQuery dataTables plugin. When I `POST` a request for data to the server, `dataTables` provides lots of info regarding ordering, search values (if any), and column metadata.

Using the Chrome debugger, I see that the data ready to be sent in the `POST` request is a properly formed `JSON` object (snippet below from within the `dataTables` object)

```
"ajax": { // define ajax settings
    ...
    "type": "POST", // request type
    "timeout": 20000,
    "data": function(data) { // add request parameters before submit    
        $.each(ajaxParams, function(key, value) {
            data[key] = value;
        });
        var data = JSON.stringify(data); // here, the data is properly formed JSON. I tried stringifying it to no avail
    },
```

In my view on the server (using `Python` & `Flask`), I see the data comes through like below (I used a screenshot from PyCharm so you can see the details of how the data comes across).

[image]

So far, I have tried playing with the `json` and `formencode` modules on the server and tried to stringify the data before sending from the client, but nothing changes. Datatype on the server is a `Werkzeug CombinedMultiDict`, although I don't think that matters at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In Ajax set:

```
type: "POST",

data: data,

dataType: "json",

contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

and then in flask just use:

```
import json

...

data = jsonify(request.get_json(force=True))
```

Comment: I tried your solution and now `request.values` is empty and 'request.data' contains the following string: `draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname...` Where `&` = `,`, `%5B` = `[`, and `%5D` = `]` if matching to the original `request.values `

Comment: Make sure that the 'data' in the JSON request is a properly formatted JSON and then in flask use request.get_json and not request.data, as shown above. Take a look at the documentation of the get_json() method at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/ .